# How to select next ul on click event using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking in other questions, but I couldn`t find answer.

I have code like this:

```
<div class="chacter_form">
    <form id="new_character" class="new_character" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/1/characters">   
        <ul class="no_dot form_partial active_partial"></ul>
        <ul class="no_dot hide form_partial test"></ul>
        <ul class="no_dot hide form_partial"></ul>
    </form>
    <button id="prev_form_button"></button>
    <button id="next_form_button"></button>
</div>
```

Of course every `ul` has some number of `li`. I want to write a jQuery function that when `#next_form_button` is clicked it will hide first `ul` and show the second. `hide` class set display to none.

This is my attempt but it is not working:

```
$(document).on('click', '#next_form_button', function(){
    $active_partial = $('ul.active_partial')
    $next_partial = $('ul.active_partial').next('ul')
    $active_partial.removeClass('active_partial').fadeToggle()
    $next_partial.addClass('active_partial').fadeToggle()
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector to finding visible `ul` and use [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to finding next `ul`.

```js
$("#next").click(function(){
    if ($("ul:visible").index() < 2)
        $("ul:visible").hide().next().show();
});

$("#prev").click(function(){
    if ($("ul:visible").index() > 0)
        $("ul:visible").hide().prev().show();
});
```

```css
ul:nth-child(2),
ul:nth-child(3) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>D</li>
        <li>E</li>
        <li>F</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>G</li>
        <li>H</li>
        <li>I</li>
    </ul>
    <button id="prev">Prev</button>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete `snippet` you will find it very handy :)

**Thanks**

```js
$(function(){
  var allUL = $("form ul").length;
  $("#next_form_button").click(function(){
   allUL--;
   var currentUL = $(".active_partial");
     if(allUL == 0){        $(currentUL).removeClass("active_partial").addClass("hide");
     $("form ul:eq(0)").addClass("active_partial").removeClass("hide");
allUL = $("form ul").length;
    } else {    $(currentUL).next("ul").addClass("active_partial").removeClass("hide");
     $(currentUL).removeClass("active_partial").addClass("hide");
        }
});
  
  $("#prev_form_button").click(function(){
    allUL++;
    var currentUL = $(".active_partial");
    if(allUL > 3){ $(currentUL).removeClass("active_partial").addClass("hide");
    $("form ul:eq(2)").addClass("active_partial").removeClass("hide");
allUL = $("form ul").length - 2;
    } else { $(currentUL).prev("ul").addClass("active_partial").removeClass("hide");
   $(currentUL).removeClass("active_partial").addClass("hide");
        }
});
  
});
```

```css
.hide{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chacter_form">

    <form id="new_character" class="new_character" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/1/characters">

    <ul class="no_dot form_partial active_partial">
      <li>ul li 1</li>
      <li>ul li 1</li>
      <li>ul li 1</li>
      <li>ul li 1</li>
      </ul>
    <ul class="no_dot hide form_partial test">
      <li>ul li 2</li>
      <li>ul li 2</li>
      <li>ul li 2</li>
      <li>ul li 2</li>
      </ul>
    <ul class="no_dot hide form_partial">
      <li>ul li 3</li>
      <li>ul li 3</li>
      <li>ul li 3</li>
      <li>ul li 3</li>
      </ul>

</form>
<button id="prev_form_button">Prev</button>

<button id="next_form_button">Next</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.toogleClass();](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```js
$('#next_form_button').click(function(){
  $active_partial = $('ul.active_partial');
  $next_partial = $('ul.active_partial').next('ul');
  $active_partial.removeClass('active_partial').toggleClass('hide');
  $next_partial.addClass('active_partial').toggleClass('hide');
 });
```

```css
.hide{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chacter_form">

    <form id="new_character" class="new_character" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/1/characters">
    <ul class="no_dot form_partial active_partial" >first</ul>
    <ul class="no_dot hide form_partial test">second</ul>
    <ul class="no_dot hide form_partial">Third</ul>
</form>
<button id="prev_form_button"></button>

<button id="next_form_button">toggle</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks your code itself working, with slight modification

```
$(document).on('click', '#next_form_button', function(){
    $active_partial = $('ul.active_partial')
    $next_partial = $('ul.active_partial').next('ul')
    $active_partial.removeClass('active_partial').fadeToggle()
    $next_partial.addClass('active_partial').show()
});
```

Comment: keep the click handler inside the document.ready and try again

Comment: document.on ensure that the dome is loading. The code above hide first ul as expected it just don`t show the other ul

Comment: Updated the answer